# React Native toggle add/remove element in an array based off toggling a button

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, touchableopacity

I have a `TouchableOpacity` that can be both pressed and unpressed.

Here is my useState variable:

`const [isPressMonday, setIsPressMonday] = useState(false);`

and here is my toggling function:

```
    setIsPressMonday(!isPressMonday);
    setDays(days => [...days, 'Monday']) 

  };
```

The thing is, when a user un-clicks the button, it should remove Monday from the array. This would be simple if I could just check `if(!isPressMonday)` and remove it from the array, but the default is `false` so that is almost always true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to check with `isPressMonday` state instead check if `'Monday'` present in `days` state. If yes, remove else, add.

```
//assuming 'days' is your array state name
setIsPressMonday(isPressMonday => !isPressMonday);
const index = days.indexOf('Monday');
if (index !== -1) {
  let tempDays = days
  tempDays.splice(index, 1);
  setDays(tempDays)
}
else {
  setDays(days => [...days, 'Monday'])
}
```